# Configuring parallelism in Storm

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-storm

I am new to Apache Storm, and I am trying to figure for myself about configuring storm parallelism. So there is a great article "[Understanding the Parallelism of a Storm Topology](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html)", but it only arouses questions.

When you have a multinode storm cluster each topology is distributed as a whole according to `TOPOLOGY_WORKERS` configuration parameter. So if you have 5 workers, then you have 5 copies of spout (1 per worker), and the same thing is with bolts.

How to deal with situation like this inside a storm cluster (preferably without creating external services):

1. I need exactly one spout used by all instances of topology, for example if input data is being pushed to cluster via a net folder, which is scanned for new files.
2. Similar issue with concrete type of bolts. For example when data is processed by licensed third-party library which is locked to a concrete physical machine.

Comment: No, you are wrong, the number of instances (tasks) is for the cluster. Not per worker.

Comment: 5 workers doesn't mean 5 copies of Spout. if you want to make 5 copies of Spout you have to make number of executors 5 for that spout. each worker process run some part of topology. if you have 5 workers that mean 5 workers threads are available to run N Bolts executors + N Spouts executors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the basics:

1. Workers - Run executors, each worker has its own JVM
2. Executors - Run tasks, each executor is distributed across various workers by storm
3. Tasks - Instances running your spout/bolt code

Second, a correction... having 5 workers does NOT mean you will automatically have 5 copies of your spout. Having 5 workers means you have 5 separate JVMs where storm can assign executors to run (think of this as 5 buckets).

The number of instances of your spout is configured when you first create and submit your topology:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("0-spout", new MySpout(), spoutParallelism).setNumTasks(spoutTasks);
```

Since you want only one spout for the entire cluster, you'd set both `spoutParallelism` and `spoutTasks` to 1.

Comment: Thanks! And about part my second question. Can I say to storm something like "start such bolt only on this machine"?

Comment: No, Storm automatically determines which workers go on which machines.

Comment: @Redwan for running specific bolts on specific machine you can have look in the [storm's pluggable scheduler](http://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/)