# How to interpret storm's parallelism?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm new to Apache Storm and got confused about the parallelism thing.

Imagine for a topology that 1 spout and 8 worker bolts and 1 aggregator bolt.

when I use

```
topoBuilder.setSpout("spout", new Spout(), 1);
topoBuilder.setBolt("worker", new WorkerBolt(), 5);
topoBuilder.setBolt("aggregator", new AggregatorBolt(), 1);
```

and the topology is set, and if I use

```
conf.setWorkerNum(2);
```

There exists 2 worker processes, each one of them consists of a topology, i.e. 1 spout, 5 worker bolts and 1 aggregator bolt.

> Q1. So in total I got 2 spouts, 10 worker bolts and 2 aggregator bolts. Is that correct?

I'm trying to measure a grouping method and the number of instances of the worker bolts does have a great influence on the result.

> Q2. If I want to change the number of instances of worker bolts, I should simply change `topoBuilder.setBolt("worker", new WorkerBolt(), 20);`, or should I change `conf.setWorkerNum(4);`?

Comment: Similar question, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27784254/98933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer - I'm also a newbie but I'll try to answer based on how I understand Storm ATM.

Q1. No. Setting `numWorkers` AKA "topology.workers" decides how many worker processes (slots) your topology will allocate in the cluster. Your bolts will be divided between all slots. So you will have 1 spout instances, 5 worker bolt instances and 1 aggregator bolt instances spread out over 2 worker processes. Instances are called `tasks` in Storm documentation.

Q2. First option.

Worth mentioning is that there is also another parameter, `builder.setBolt(...).setNumTasks(x)`. This controls how many instances you will get of your bolt/spout. By default this will be equal to the number of executors (threads) as specified by parallelism_hint, but you can have a higher task count than executor count if you want to have some headroom for scaling your topology.